# Selecting and Printing multiple sheets at once based on a cell value on each sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a document with 500 + WorkSheets and trying to print all the ones where G1 = "Print" as a Single document.

My steps are to create an array and store the matching worksheet names. Next is to select that worksheets from the array and print them.

```
Sub Help()

 Dim MyArray() As Variant
 Dim I As Long
 Dim MyArray_Count As Integer
   MyArray_Count = 0

 Worksheet_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

 For I = 1 To Worksheet_Count
   If Worksheets(I).Range("G1").Value = "Print" Then
       MyArray_Count = MyArray_Count + 1
       MyArray(MyArray_Count) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name ' 'Having error here
   End If

 Next I

 Worksheets(MyArray).Select 'having error here

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the important piece you are missing is `Redim Preserve`.

I changed a few things to keep it simple. I tried to stick closely to your design. As you can see, you also have to plan for what happens when none of them meet the condition.

```
Sub Help()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim MyArray() As String
  ReDim MyArray(0)

  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Range("G1").Value = "Print" Then
      If Len(MyArray(0)) > 0 Then ReDim Preserve MyArray(UBound(MyArray) + 1)
      MyArray(UBound(MyArray)) = ws.Name
    End If
  Next

  If Len(MyArray(0)) > 0 Then
     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(MyArray).Select
  Else
     MsgBox "none found"
  End If
 
End Sub
```

<sub>Note: Keep in mind that "Print" in your cell is not the same thing as "print" or "PRINT"</sub>

Here is a better `If` statement to address that:

```
If UCase$(Trim$(ws.Range("G1").Value)) = "PRINT" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

### Dictionary vs Array

**Dictionary**

- You don't know how many worksheets will be added, therefore using the dictionary presents a more suitable (easier) solution. Also, using a `For Each...Next` loop makes it kind of more readable and emphasizes that the number of worksheets is not relevant.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HelpDictionary()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If you're dealing with the workbook containing this code, instead use:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cString As String
    
    ' Add the worksheet names to the dictionary.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        cString = CStr(ws.Range("G1").Value)
        If StrComp(cString, "Print", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' 'PRINT = print'
            dict(ws.Name) = Empty ' only interested in the keys
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Check if any worksheet name was added.
    If dict.Count = 0 Then ' no worksheet name added
        MsgBox "No worksheets to select.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' at least one worksheet name was added
    End If
    
    wb.Worksheets(dict.Keys).Select

    MsgBox "The following worksheets are selected: " _
        & vbLf & Join(dict.Keys, vbLf), vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**Array**

- This is also a valid solution. Compare it with the dictionary solution to see how it is more complicated.

```vb
Sub HelpArray()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' If you're dealing with the workbook containing this code, instead use:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim aCount As Long: aCount = wb.Worksheets.Count
    
    Dim MyArray() As String: ReDim MyArray(1 To aCount) ' to fit 'a'll names
    
    Dim cString As String
    Dim a As Long ' 'a'll worksheets
    Dim p As Long ' worksheets to 'p'rint
    
    ' Add the worksheet names to the array.
    For a = 1 To aCount
        cString = CStr(Worksheets(a).Range("G1").Value)
        If StrComp(cString, "Print", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' 'PRINT = print'
            p = p + 1
            MyArray(p) = wb.Worksheets(a).Name
        End If
    Next a
    
    ' Check if any worksheet name was added.
    If p = 0 Then ' no worksheet name added
        MsgBox "No worksheets to select.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' at least one worksheet name was added
    End If
    
    ' Resize if not all worksheet names.
    If p < aCount Then ' not all worksheet names added
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(1 To p)
    'Else ' all worksheet names added
    End If
    
    wb.Worksheets(MyArray).Select

    MsgBox "The following worksheets are selected: " _
        & vbLf & Join(MyArray, vbLf), vbInformation
    
End Sub
```